# AttributeError: 'Fighter' object has no attribute 'Fighter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, super, attributeerror

I'm new to this and I'm getting an error that I was hoping someone could help me with and explain my error.

Error:

> line 178, in applyThrust
>   shipPos = self.Fighter.getPos(self.origin)
>   AttributeError: 'Fighter' object has no attribute 'Fighter'

```
    class Fighter(SphereCollideObj, object):
        fighterCount = 0

        def __init__(self, modelPath, parentNode, nodeName, posVec, traverser, scaleVec = 1.0):
            super(Fighter, self).__init__(modelPath, parentNode, nodeName, 0, 0, 0, 3.0)
            self.modelNode.setScale(scaleVec)
            self.modelNode.setPos(posVec)

            self.trav = traverser

            self.origin = render.attachNewNode("origin")
            self.origin.setPos(0, 0, 0)
            self.origin.hide()

            self.setKeyBindings()

            self.hud = Hud("./Tools/Hud.x", self.modelNode, "Hud", (0, 10, 0))



        def setKeyBindings(self):
            self.accept("space", self.thrust, [1])
            self.accept("space-up", self.thrust, [0])

        def thrust(self,keyDown):
            if keyDown:
                taskMgr.add(self.applyThrust, "thrust")
            else:
                taskMgr.remove("thrust")
                self.acceptOnce("space", self.thrust,[1])
                self.acceptOnce("space-up", self.thrust,[0])
        def applyThrust(self, task):
            shipPos = self.Fighter.getPos(self.origin)
            hudPos = self.hud.modelNode.getPos(self.origin)

            trajectory = hudPos - shipPos
            rate = 5
            trajectory.normalize()
            self.Fighter.setFluidPos(shipPos + trajectory * rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "self" in this case? I mean, what class of object does it represent? 
I think the error message is quite helpful.

def applyThrust(self, task) --> method of class Fighter.

self.Fighter --> calling the "Fighter" member or attribute of "self" which is Fighter instance in this case.

You will get the same error in self.Fighter.setFluidPos(...)

Answer (score 0):

I think what Mircea is trying to say is that the `Fighter` in `self.Fighter.getPos(self.origin)` is redundant. Seeing as the object is of class `Fighter`, `self.getPos(self.origin)` should be enough (given that the super-class has a method called `getPos()`, you're not showing the code for it).